# Spring war files run differently based on if they are deployed through Eclipse vs Intellij

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a set of 4 Spring war files that I am deploying into a local Tomcat instance.

When launched via Eclipse, with a Tomcat server configuration, it starts up as expected. When trying to deploy to the same local Tomcat deployment via an Intellij Run configuration, however, Tomcat starts up, the wars deploy and complete like 99% of their startup process, but the applications within the wars never fully initialize.

The two have the same JVM args and are using the same context configurations.

Comment: Did you check the logs in the Tomcat instance?

Comment: @artemisian The Tomcat log directory is empty. The output logs from Intellij and Eclipse are not obviously different but startup is so involved it takes like 15 minutes so it's hard to comb over.